# Performance difference with various List initialization and population techniques

Tags: c#, performance, list

I was trying to find out if setting the capacity of a list in the constructor could flatten the already negligible performance differences between using `List<T>(IEnumerable<T>)` vs `List<T>()` + `AddRange(IEnumerable<T>)`.

I found out **setting the capacity** before `AddRange()` actually **leads to roughly the same performance** of constructing the list with an initial collection.

But there's more. What if you use `Add()` instead of `AddRange()`? For some reason it seems like the **performance improves by a 32%**.

So what if I use `Add()` without initializing the constructor of the list with a initial capacity? It seems like the performance are worst than the previous Add() approach, but still better than `AddRange()` approach: there's a performance boost of a 26%.

This is strange enough for me to wonder if my test was a valid one; so I post the tests I did (run in release mode without debugger).

Can anybody confirm this?

```
int items = 100000;
int cycles = 10000;

var collectionToCopy = Enumerable.Range( 0, items );

var sw0 = new Stopwatch();
sw0.Start();
for( int i = 0; i < cycles; i++ )
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>( collectionToCopy );
}
sw0.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( sw0.ElapsedMilliseconds );

var sw1 = new Stopwatch();
sw1.Start();
for( int i = 0; i < cycles; i++ )
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>( items );
    list.AddRange( collectionToCopy );
}
sw1.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( sw1.ElapsedMilliseconds );

var sw4 = new Stopwatch();
sw4.Start();
for( int i = 0; i < cycles; i++ )
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    list.AddRange( collectionToCopy );
}
sw4.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( sw4.ElapsedMilliseconds );

var sw2 = new Stopwatch();
sw2.Start();
for( int i = 0; i < cycles; i++ )
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>( items );
    foreach( var item in collectionToCopy )
        list.Add( item );
}
sw2.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( sw2.ElapsedMilliseconds );

var sw3 = new Stopwatch();
sw3.Start();
for( int i = 0; i < cycles; i++ )
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    foreach( var item in collectionToCopy )
        list.Add( item );
}
sw3.Stop();
Console.WriteLine( sw3.ElapsedMilliseconds );
```

> RESULTS:
>
> 13400 - constructor initialized with collection
>
> 13423 - constructor initialized with capacity + AddRange(collection)
>
> 14857 - parameterless constructor + AddRange(collection)
>
> 9003 - constructor initialized with capacity + Add(item)
>
> 9841 - parameterless constructor + Add(item)

Comment: FYI: I have achieved pretty similar results with no major difference from yours. Seems strange that AddRange() is slower than Add()Maybe some of the C# gurus will elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devil is in `Enumerable.Range(0, items)`. Changing it to `Enumerable.Range(0, items).ToList();` will get you the expected result.

`AddRange(IEnumerable collectionToCopy)` will check the actual type of the input. If the input is continuous(e.g. list, array, ...), it will try to copy. Otherwise, it falls back to enumeration and simple Add().

And this is the fallback code

```
using(IEnumerator<T> en = collection.GetEnumerator()) {
   while(en.MoveNext()) {
        Insert(index++, en.Current);
```

In the fallback case, the worse performance given by List.AddRange may have come from the IEnumertor overhead